# Can't seem to invoke a program that has two classes. Beginner in Python, was hoping to learn more about invocation rules

Tags: python

I'm dealing with the following Water Buckets program, where I can't seem to invoke the program since it as two classes and the first class is used with the second. I'm just a beginner so I was wondering what I'm doing wrong in the invocation process and what rules beginners like me should be aware of to avoid these problems.

I did some research, but I found it hard to adapt the solutions to this problem since I'm not sure what the error means when it says "dict' object has no attribute 'has_key''. It would be great if it could be put in simpler terms since many people (including me) are new to CS and Python.

Code:

```
class manager:
    """ Manage game queue. keep track of states already seen
      and who their parent states are"""
    def __init__ (self) :
        self.queue = []
        self.seen  = {}

    def getState (self) :
        "return next state and pop it off the queue"

        if not self.queue : return None
        state = self.queue[0]
        self.queue = self.queue[1:]
        return state

    def addState (self, parentState, newState) :
        "add state if it's new. Remember its parent"
        if self.seen.has_key(str(newState)) : return
        self.seen[str(newState)] = str(parentState)
        self.queue.append (newState)
        #print '--- Adding ', newState

    def getSolution (self) :
        "Return solution from latest state added"
        solution = []
        state = self.queue[-1]
        while state :
            solution.append (str(state))
            state = self.getParent(state)
        solution.reverse()
        return solution

    def getParent (self, childState) :
        """return parent of state, if it exists"""
        try    : return self.seen[str(childState)]
        except : return None

class bucketPlayer:
    def __init__ (self, manager) :
        self.manager = manager

    def test (self, oldstate, newstate) :
        [newA, newB] = newstate
        won = (newA == self.goal or newB == self.goal)
        self.manager.addState (oldstate, newstate)
        return won

    def playGame (self, aMax, bMax, goal) :
        "grab a state and generate 8 more to submit to the manager"
        self.goal = goal
        self.manager.addState("", [0,0])   # start with 2 empty buckets
        while 1 :
            oldstate = self.manager.getState()
            [aHas,bHas] = oldstate
            if self.test (oldstate, [aMax,bHas]): break # fill A from well
            if self.test (oldstate, [0   ,bHas]): break # empty A to well
            if self.test (oldstate, [aHas,bMax]): break # fill B from well
            if self.test (oldstate, [aHas,0   ]): break # empty B to well
            howmuch = min(aHas, bMax-bHas)
            if self.test (oldstate, [aHas-howmuch,bHas+howmuch]): break # pour A to B
            howmuch = min(bHas, aMax-aHas)
            if self.test (oldstate, [aHas+howmuch,bHas-howmuch]): break # pour B to A
        print ("Solution is: ")
        print (string.join (self.manager.getSolution(), "\n"))


m = manager()
p = bucketPlayer(m)
# A=7 liters, B=11 liters, Want=6
p.playGame(7,11,6)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Python 3.4/Portfolio Projects/Project 4.py", line 70, in <module>
    p.playGame(7,11,6)
  File "/Applications/Python 3.4/Portfolio Projects/Project 4.py", line 51, in playGame
    self.manager.addState("", [0,0])   # start with 2 empty buckets
  File "/Applications/Python 3.4/Portfolio Projects/Project 4.py", line 18, in addState
    if self.seen.has_key(str(newState)) : return
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Comment: [has_key](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) was removed in Python 3.X Use `in` instead.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) might help give you a *leg-up*.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with multiple classes or "invocation rules".

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting familiar with the differences between Python 2 and 3. I think that's why I was confused with my research.

Answer (score 2):

The older [has_key](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key) method has been depricated and [was removed completely](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) in Python 3.x

Use `if key in dict:` form of the [in conditional](https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/expressions.html#in) instead:

```
if str(newState) in self.seen : return
```

Comment: I'm still getting familiar with the differences between Python 2 and 3, that's why I think I was getting confused. I changed the syntax and removed the string.join function and it now works. Thank you I really appreciate it.